# Changing the cursor appearance in Visual Studio Code via extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to change the cursor appearance in Visual Studio Code using the extensions API?  Knowing that VS Code is built on top of Chromium, and that there isn't a way to style the text cursor in a browser using CSS, it wouldn't seem likely.

I'm messing around and trying to implement some simple modal editing, and I would like to create a block cursor like vim in normal mode.

Comment: It's possible. The "Vim" extension does it. However, my cursor is now permanently stuck as a block cursor after disabling that plugin and I can't figure out to change it back!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure about using the extension API, but you can do it via your user preferences file (which extensions must be able to modify because the "Vim" extension does it as mentioned in my comment above):

File -> Preferences -> User Settings

Place the following in `settings.json`:

```js
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    // Controls the cursor style, accepted values are 'block', 'line' and 'underline'
    "editor.cursorStyle": "block"
}
```

Comment: how about the mouse cursor icons?